# md-grid-list inside md-grid-tile in Angular Material2 is not visible

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have code like given below in Angular Material 2

```
    <md-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
      <md-grid-tile>1 
        <div>
          <md-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="1:1">
            <md-grid-tile colspan="2">5</md-grid-tile>
            <md-grid-tile >6</md-grid-tile>
            <md-grid-tile>7</md-grid-tile>
            <md-grid-tile >8</md-grid-tile>
            <md-grid-tile >9</md-grid-tile>
          </md-grid-list>
        </div>
      </md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile >2</md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile>3</md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile>4</md-grid-tile>
    </md-grid-list>
```

Now  ** div** tag and md-grid-list is not visible inside it.

**Updated- Solution for the same**

```
        <md-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
      <md-grid-tile class="shape">1 
        <div class="shape1">
          <md-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="1:1">
            <md-grid-tile >5</md-grid-tile>
            <md-grid-tile >6</md-grid-tile>
            <md-grid-tile>7</md-grid-tile>
            <md-grid-tile >6</md-grid-tile>
          </md-grid-list>
        </div>
      </md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile class="shape">2</md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile class="shape">3</md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile class="shape">4</md-grid-tile>
    </md-grid-list>
```

Where CSS is given below.

```
        .shape{       
            background:#ffd600;
        }
        .shape1{
            background:#651fff;   
            width: 50%;    
        }
```

Comment: please share plunker or jsfiddle for this

Comment: Hi amit,Thanks for reply. i got the solution,as md-grid-tile is getting calculated ,we need to add width to inner div. will add the solution for same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your div is collapsed. Try it like this:

```
<md-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
      <md-grid-tile>
         <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: red;">
          <md-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
            <md-grid-tile>6</md-grid-tile>
            <md-grid-tile>7</md-grid-tile>
            <md-grid-tile>8</md-grid-tile>
            <md-grid-tile>9</md-grid-tile>
          </md-grid-list>
         </div>
        </md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile >2</md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile>3</md-grid-tile>
      <md-grid-tile>4</md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

Working plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/kc74shHgRLtMLF5WITBT?p=preview)

Comment: Hi @BogdanC,Thanks for reply, it has to do something with md-grid-tile which is collapsed?,As my div was not having any style or class applied. even if i  remove my div only, it will be same( not visible) ,until i give it,some width, just curious to know.

Comment: If you look at your added div and all the children elements, they all have `height: 0` and `width:0`. It's like there is no content inside to push the element from 0. Could also be related with the `md-grid-tile` that is the parent in this case and has `overflow: hidden`